# NSPredicate for array of Dictionaries generating null array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm a Begginer in Objective-C coding and I need some help on NSPredicates.

I need to filter (by id_especie) an Array of Dictionaries that I've parsed from a Json file and retrieve the data to another array. Unfortunate all I got is a null array;

That's my Array of Dictionaries (id_especie mean species_id and id_raca mean breed_id) :

```
{
    "id_especie" = 1;
    "id_raca" = 1;
    raca = Afghanhound;
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 1;
    "id_raca" = 2;
    raca = "Airedale Terrier";
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 1;
    "id_raca" = 3;
    raca = Akita;
},...,
    {
    "id_especie" = 2;
    "id_raca" = 47;
    raca = "N/I";
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 2;
    "id_raca" = 48;
    raca = Siames;
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 3;
    "id_raca" = 49;
    raca = Periquito;
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 4;
    "id_raca" = 50;
    raca = Cobra;
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 4;
    "id_raca" = 51;
    raca = Lagarto;
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 5;
    "id_raca" = 52;
    raca = "Furao";
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 5;
    "id_raca" = 53;
    raca = Hamster;
},
    {
    "id_especie" = 6;
    "id_raca" = 54;
    raca = Outros;
}
```

And this is my code:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayBreedAndSpecies;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *filteredArray; //edited
```

.m

```
NSError  *errorLoad = nil;
NSURL    *jsonUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://marcosdegni.com.br/petsistema/teste/raca.php"];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorLoad];

if (!errorLoad) {
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    self.arrayBreedAndSpecies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:jsonArray];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ = %@",@"id_especie", @"2"];
[self.filteredArray setArray: [self.arrayBreedAndSpecies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
NSLog(@"Filter: %@", self.filteredArray);
```

Comment: well that is the description of you dictionaries, if I wanted to try to repro your problem, I would have to reconstruct your dictionaries...

Comment: Hello Grady, thanks for you time...please find the full dictionary at http://marcosdegni.com.br/petsistema/teste/raca.php". If you copy the entire code to a iOS project you will have it loaded as arrayBreedAndSprecies...tks

Comment: the predicate has to be formatted with `@K` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've noticed a few errors with your NSPredicate code:

1) A dynamic key path in a predicate should be `%K` not `%@`.

2) To check if a number value is equal to another you need to use `==` not just `=`

Therefore the last section of code should be:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %i",@"id_especie", 2];
self.filteredArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.arrayBreedAndSpecies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
NSLog(@"Filter: %@", self.filteredArray);
```

I'm assuming here that the `id_especie` property is a number value. If it is a string value you could use the predicate: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K MATCHES[cd] %@", @"id_especie", @"2"];`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

just a guess here, because there isn't a working code example here:

```
[self.filteredArray setArray: [self.arrayBreedAndSpecies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

if self.filteredArray is nil, that line will do nothing... I bet you really mean:

```
self.filteredArray = [self.arrayBreedAndSpecies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```